# Oracle Query takes ages to execute

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this below Oracle query. It takes ages to execute.

```
Select Distinct Z.WH_Source,
   substr(Z.L_Y_Month,0,4) || '-' || substr(Z.L_Y_Month,5) Ld_Yr_Mth, 
m.model_Name, p.SR, p.PLATE_NO, pp.value, z.CNT_number, z.platform_SR_number, 
z.account_name, z.owner_name, z.operator_name, z.jetcare_expiry_date, z.wave, 
z.address, z.country, substr(z.CNT_status, 10) ctstatus,
ALLOEM.GET_CNT_TYRE_SR@TNS_GG(z.CNT_number, Z.WH_Source, Z.L_Y_Month,
                              z.platform_SR_number, '¿') 
product_SR_number
From MST.ROLE p
inner join MST.model m on m.model_id = p.model_id
left join MST.ROLEproperty pp on pp.ROLE_id = p.ROLE_id 
      and pp.property_lookup = 'SSG-WH-ENROLL'
left join alloem.Z_SSG_HM_LOG@TNS_GG z on z.camp_ac_ROLE_id = p.ROLE_id
Where 
    1 = 1 or z.L_Y_Month = 1
 Order By 1, 2 desc, 3,4
```

If i remove this line,

```
ALLOEM.GET_CNT_TYRE_SR@TNS_GG(z.CNT_number, Z.WH_Source, Z.L_Y_Month,
                              z.platform_SR_number, '¿')
```

it executes very fast. But, I can't remove the line.  Is there any way to make this query to execute fast.?

Answer (score 0):

> *If i remove this line,*
>
> ```
> ALLOEM.GET_CNT_TYRE_SR@TNS_GG(z.CNT_number, Z.WH_Source,
>   Z.L_Y_Month, z.platform_SR_number, '¿')
> ```
>
> *it executes very fast. But, I can't remove the line. Is there any way to make this query to execute fast.?*

Query tuning is a complex thing. Without table structures, indexes, execution plan or statistics it is very hard to provide one universal answer.

Anyway I would try [scalar subquery caching](https://blog.jooq.org/2011/09/02/oracle-scalar-subquery-caching/)(if applicable):

```
ALLOEM.GET_CNT_TYRE_SR@TNS_GG(z.CNT_number, Z.WH_Source, Z.L_Y_Month, 
                              z.platform_SR_number, '¿') 
=>    
(SELECT ALLOEM.GET_CNT_TYRE_SR@TNS_GG(z.CNT_number, Z.WH_Source,Z.L_Y_Month,
                                        z.platform_SR_number, '¿') FROM dual)
```

---

Also usage of `DISTINCT` may indicate some problems with normalization. If possible please fix underlying problem and remove it.

Finally you should avoid using positional `ORDER BY` (it is commom anti-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
alloem.Z_SSG_HM_LOG@TNS_GG
```

suggests that you fetch data over a database link. It is *usually* slower than fetching data locally. So, if you can afford it & if your query manipulates "static" data (i.e. nothing changes in `Z_SSG_HM_LOG` table frequently) and - even if it does - the amount of data isn't very high, consider creating a **materialized view** (MV) in schema you're connected to while running that query. You can even create index(es) on a MV so ... hopefully, everything will run faster without too much effort.